# Best practice for closing websocket in android

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I am using this [library](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) for connecting to a websocket server from android.

Specifically this part :

```
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket("ws://192.168.2.10:8000/temp" , "my-protocol", new WebSocketConnectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception ex, WebSocket webSocket) {
        if (ex != null) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        webSocket.send("a string");
        webSocket.setStringCallback(new StringCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStringAvailable(String s) {
                Debug.Log( LOGTAG ,"I got a string: " + s);
            }
        });
        webSocket.close(); // issue here
    }
});
```

I would like to close the socket when I click a button. Now everytime I want to send a message to the socket I open it and close it.

I would like to open it once and keep it alive and close it when I click a close button. My idea was to pass a variable to the WebSocketConnectCallback and make a static variable and based on this variable close the socket.

I would like to know what is the best practice in a situation like this.

Comment: Are you using ASyncTask or a Service?

Comment: asyncTask... this essentially is coming from the library underneath and I do not control it explicitly. I create this on my main thread directly and it creates the task underneath

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the Application class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html):

Inherid your own class for Application and here you can track the socket, open it, close it as you need.

See a tutorial (first google match, maybe there is a better one): http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/

So basically extend Application and add your class in the manifest file as application class.

Your may add a timer that might close the socket after several time while not used.